# What is the meaning of $a \vee b$ resp.?

Tags: probability, self-study

I am reading René Schilling' book "Measures, Integrals and Martingales". I learned this book a few years ago, but need to re-read it.

Now I even get confused at Prelude session. Please see the sentence with the red line. Can someone help me to understand what this sentence means?

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a \lor b = \max(a,b)$

$a \land b = \min(a,b)$

These are two separate things packed into one sentence via "resp.", which is short for respectively.

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you very much. If he says " $a \vee b$ and $a \wedge b$ denote the maximum and mininum of numbers $a, b \in R$, respetively. It is probablely much easier for me to understand.

Comment: Yes. I merely explained what the sentence meant. I did not advocate it as being the greatest piece of mathematical writing in history. :)